# .NET - When serializing a container with data to JSON, how can I hide the container?

Tags: c#, json, serialization, asp.net-web-api, json.net

So i'm trying to serialize a container object with some data to JSON (using Newtonsoft's JSON.NET), and I would like to hide the fact that the data is contained (so the serialization output should only be the contained data, not the container as well).

Example:

```
class DataObject {
    public string MyProperty { get; set; }
}

class ContainerClass<T> {
    public T Data { get; set; }
}

var myObject = new ContainerClass<DataObject> {
                   Data = new DataObject { MyProperty = "test-data" }
               };
```

Which now serializes to:

```
{ "Data": { "MyProperty": "test-data" } }
```

But I want to have the following output:

```
{ "MyProperty": "test-data" }
```

Are there any attributes I can use, or other methods (without writing my own custom JsonConverter implementation) to get the desired JSON output?

**EDIT**: so there are some questions regarding the serialization. As I've commented, I'm using ASP.NET Web API which serializes the result of an action to JSON. The code is something similar to this:

```
abstract class BaseActionResult {}
class ContainerClass<T> : BaseActionResult { ... }
class ErrorResult : BaseActionResult { ... }

public class MyController : ApiController {

    [HttpGet]
    public BaseActionResult MyAction() {
        // ... do stuff

        if (error) return new ErrorResult();

        return new ContainerClass<DataObject> {
                   Data = new DataObject { MyProperty = "test-data" }
               };
    }

}
```

Comment: Please show your serialization code. The obvious option would be to serialize not `ContainerClass`, but just `DataObject`. The silly way would be to serialize, then parse, remove the root, and use the result of that.

Comment: Ok, so I'm using ASP.NET Web API, and the return type of the action is the container class. Web API then serializes this object to JSON. The problem is that the return type of the action should be the container class (or rather, the abstract class it extends), so I can't change the signature to return a DataObject.

Comment: If the signature and return type cannot change then the JSON returned cannot change.  JSON.net will serialize the data based on the object you pass to it. So if you need to return only a serialized DataObject, the return type of the function must change.

Comment: I would imagine that if I write my own JsonConverter I would be able to for the serialization to ignore the 'Data' property of the ContainerClass and directly serialize the DataObject. Therefore I was hoping this is already supported with some kind of attribute (as you can also use attributes to fully ignore certain properties of an object), but so far I gather this isn't available currently.

Answer (score 2):

Change the function that returns the JSON to return a serialized DataObject instead of a serialized ContainerClass